# HTML form and WWW prefix issue

Tags: javascript, php, forms, web

When I use form action URL with 'www' prefix, by pressing the submit button (or enter key) the form does not work: submits but won't send any variables. It does work, however, with JS submit by clicking the magnifier, even though JS code does not affect the URL (at least as far as I know).

When I remove 'www' it works both ways. Any idea what the reason is behind this?

http://www.hasznaltfaiparigep.hu/fr/index2.php

I made a gray div above the form to display POST variables.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
<title>Bonjour! :)</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="hu" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabs.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico?v=1.2">
<script>
    function addElementAndSubmitForm(formName,actionUrl,elName,elValue) {
        var form = document.forms[formName];
        form.action = actionUrl;
        var el = document.createElement("input");
        el.type = "hidden";
        el.name = elName;
        el.value = elValue;
        form.appendChild(el);
        form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <form name="myForm" method="POST" action="http://www.hasznaltfaiparigep.hu/fr/index2.php">
            <div id="debug" style="border:solid 1px black;padding:10px;margin:10px;background:#ccc;color:#555;width:96%">
            <font style="font-weight:bold">POST vars:</font>
            <?php
                if( count($_POST) > 0 ) {
                    echo "<br/><span style=\"padding-left:4px\"> ";
                    print_r($_POST); echo "</span>";
                }
            ?>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left;">
                Chercher un mot: <input type="text" id="cherfield" name="chercher" />
                <img style="padding: 0 5px; margin: 0 0 -8px 0;" src="images/chercher.jpg" onClick="javascript:addElementAndSubmitForm('myForm','#','chercher',document.getElementById('cherfield').value);"/>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="envoi" />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_input" value="whatever">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did some testing, and it looks like you may have something in your server configuration that is causing a redirect. When I submit using the submit button, I get a 301 response code and then it redirects back to itself without the www. If you look at the network tab of your browser inspector you can see it.

Comment: Indeed! interesting. Thanks for the tip, I didn't know this tool.